# Delegated condition_variable against spurious wakeup

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, locking

This is my attempt at dealing with spurious wakeups: A new class which replaced `std::condition_variable` in my code.

Some questions which came to my mind are (and I hope CR is the right place for that):

1. Is this actually effective? Or will I run into concurrency-related problems?
2. Would inheriting `std::condition_variable` be better than delegation?
3. Is it better to use `bool` guarded by a `std::mutex` or `std::atomic<bool>`?

This is the class:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Condition {
private:
    std::condition_variable _condition; // Delegation
    bool _waiting;
    std::mutex _internalMutex;
public:
    Condition()
        : _waiting(false) {}

    void wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_internalMutex);
        _waiting = true;
        _condition.wait(lock, [this]() { return !_waiting; });
    }

    template< class Rep, class Period >
    void wait_for(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock,
                  const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& relTime)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_internalMutex);
        _waiting = true;
        _condition.wait_for(lock, relTime, [this]() { return !_waiting; });
    }

    template< class Clock, class Duration >
    void wait_until(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock,
                    const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timeoutTime)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_internalMutex);
        _waiting = true;
        _condition.wait_until(lock, timeoutTime, [this]() { return !_waiting; });
    }

    void notify_all()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_internalMutex);
        _waiting = false;
        _condition.notify_all();
    }

    void notify_one()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_internalMutex);
        _waiting = false;
        _condition.notify_one();
    }
};
```

The usage would be the same as with `std::condition_variable` (but without the typical caveat that you have to prevent spurious wakeups by encapsulating `.wait()` with a predicate check.

Comment: Right now, if the `wait_until` times out before any `notify_X`, doesn't `_waiting` remain `true`?  I feel like using a single boolean to represent every thread results in inconsistent state.

Comment: @sjm324 That is right, to keep the code extendable, I will set ``_waiting`` back to false. But it shouldn't change the current behavior as the flag is only evaluated directly after it has been set to true anyways, does it?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, I think setting it to `false` would be "worse".  The context of your question is about spurious wakeups, so I wonder what the goal is.  Suppose threads `A` and `B` both `wait()`.  Then `notify_one()` is issued, and `A` got woken up.  At this point, `_waiting` is **`false`**.  So if `B` gets spuriously woken up at this point, it will get unleashed because the `notify_one()` set `_waiting` to `false` for everybody.  Is this what you want, or the opposite?  If the opposite, this is why one boolean cannot represent them all.

Comment: @sjm324 okay, as i never use ``notify_one() `` I should probably just remove it entirely and then actually as you said *not* set ``_wait`` to false

Comment: the first big issue with my code is that it actually never locked the mutex. Edited my post to fix this